# Publish and Verify the source code of a contract created by another contract on etherscan

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, bytecode, contract-verification

This is the main contract which has been verified succesfully:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc4c89dd46524c6f704e92a9cd012a3ebadadff36

This is the created contract I can't get verified:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x87a8ff476273bb8533ba94012d73911e1f4f884a

The arguments I used are: "first", false, 0, 1000000 and msg.sender (wich is my address 0xfC164e97Df905733Bc076015722CABDfdE0bDf61)

compiler version: 0.4.23+commit.124ca40d
optimization: no

I managed to get the encoded constructor arguments from abi.hashex.org:

66697273740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240000000000000000000000000fc164e97df905733bc076015722cabdfde0bdf61

Answer (score 1):

It's done.

You were most of the way there with your ABI-encoded constructor arguments.

It was necessary to copy the complete source from your verified factory to get it to compile, then pick out the `StillBank` contract. It would *have to be* the same compiler version that made the factory, leaving only the optimization to guess at.

[image]

Hope it helps.